# php preg_replace not working within foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace

I have the following structure :

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $i++;
    $string = '<span>The number is $i</span>';
    $string = preg_replace('/\<span.*?\/>$/e','',$string);
    echo $string;
  }
?>
```

It appends the `$string` the number of times `foreach` loop iterate whereas i just want it to display one time as `The number is 4` at the end of the loop. `preg_replace` works if outside of the loop. How can i `echo` the output one time and delete rest. I need to do it within the loop and not outside it.

Comment: maybe try concatenating the first definition of `$string` like so: `$string = "<span>The number is".$i."</span>"`

Comment: Erm... Couldn't you just replace the whole of that code with `echo '<span>The number is '.count($users).'</span>';` ?

Comment: Why do you have to do it within the loop, if you want something to happen just once at the end, it's way more logical to do it outside th e loop...

Comment: In your foreach loop you have twice the variable **$users**. Shouldn't it be `foreach ($users as $user)`?

Comment: @RPM : This wont't work.

Comment: @DaveRandom: This can't be done because there is some other calculation going on within the loop and also we are retrieving data from the database

Comment: @user850234 Well then just maintain the `$i` counter during the loop and `echo '<span>The number is '.$i.'</span>';` at the end.

Comment: @DaveRandom : Thats what i am doing now but according to some other requirement from the client i need to put it within the loop and the other calculation that is being done within the loop and displayed should be done after it

Comment: @user850234 You mean the loop creates output, and you need the `<span>...</span>` to appear before that output?

Comment: what if you declare $string before the loop, and then just echo it after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $i++;
   if ($i == count($users)) {
      $string = '<span>The number is $i</span>';
      $string = preg_replace('/\<span.*?\/>$/e','',$string);
      echo $string;
   }
}
```

Though, you might want to consider other options for achieving this. You may maintain your `$i` variable and output it right after the loop, as this is what this does exactly.

Or, you could just `echo "<span>The number is ".count($users)."</span>";`.
In my answer, I assumed you totally can't change this things, and that your problem is more complicated than this simple `preg_replace`. If it's not, consider simplifying things.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I think you need here is [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
// Start the output buffer to catch the output from the loop
ob_start();

$i = 0;
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $i++;
  // Do stuff
}

// Stop the output buffer and get the loop output as a string
$loopOutput = ob_get_clean();

// Output everything in the correct order
echo '<span>The number is '.$i.'</span>'.$loopOutput;
```